# KeyError(u'report.purchase.quotation',) - Report Error in OpenErp

Tags: python, report, odoo, openoffice.org

I just opened a report on OpenOffice,  with the command `Edit existing Report` , made changes to it, saved a copy of the report in my desktop, then called `Send to Server` command.

But since then, when i try to print the report from any broswer, it keeps giving me this error:

```
KeyError: u'report.purchase.quotation'
2013-09-23 23:37:04,911 2008 ERROR grafibond_def openerp.netsvc: report.purchase.quotation
(<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>, KeyError(u'report.purchase.quotation',), <traceback object at 0x044DCC38>)
```

Already checked `xml` and `.py` report files, and report names seem to be Okay, could it be a problem because i saved a copy first?

Btw, since i got this error, i've tried copying the files sxw and rml saved before in my desktop with no luck.

I don't really know if i can make a new report and send it to the server, replacing or deleting the actual report files in the module? Maybe this can be solve the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this copy of your report structure and open a new a report, fill your server parameters, click on OpenERP Report Desiger/Open a new Report and paste your report structure and than Send to the Server

And Additional check your naming of report .py and .xml

Hope this will help you..

Vote for this